# Bare copper wire under kitchen sink

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

I have a bare copper wire that runs from the breaker box to the hot water hose under the kitchen sink. The electrician did this. Is this safe, if not how do I fix it?

Comment: Is there a wire from your breaker box to the *cold* water piping system somewhere? Is your water service line plastic or metal where it comes into the house?

Answer (score 2):

### Carefully inspect your *Grounding Electrode System*

**This shouldn't be it.**   The Grounding Electrode System is a fat copper ground wire that goes from your service panel to any or all of:

- Ground rods outside your house.  Code calls for 2 rods 8' long.
- an "Ufer" ground that ties into the reinforcing rod in your poured concrete foundation
- A cold water pipe where it enters the house, on the **street** side of the meter.  The problem is the utility could replace the meter with a remote-read meter, which are plastic.

Once it's proven out that the Grounding Electrode System is tip-top...

...then any *other* ground wires aren't such a big problem.

It is likely the purpose of this ground wire is not to ground the panel to actual earth (the Grounding Electrode (GES) ... But to ground an appliance to the panel (the Equipment Safety Grounding Conductor, EGC).

That is to say, maybe that ground wire isn't there to send fault current through the water heater, but rather to *prevent* fault current from a troublesome hot-water-connected device (cough dishwasher cough) from going through the water heater.

Answer (score 1):

Grounds to water lines are supposed to be to cold water lines, NOT hot water lines. Assuming there are no other earth grounds, **this is NOT safe**.

Not sure if you're in the USA or not, but if you are, a ground wire attached to copper or galvanized pipe MUST be connected within 5 feet of where the cold water enters the dwelling. If your incoming water is not metallic, copper or galvanized, and again assuming there are no other earth grounds, you'll need at least 1 ground rod added, with a ground wire, for earth ground, possibly 2 ground rods if going by recent code changes.

The way this is set up now will send any voltage meant for earth ground thru your water heater which COULD end up with some getting hurt!

Comment: The bond is supposed to be within 5' of the point of entry but many jurisdictions require both sides of the water heater to be bonded as all piping that could be energised is required to be bonded 250.104.2.B  so if this was done for that reason it is not unsafe. But there should be a bond where the pipe enters the structure or within 5' per 250.68.C.

Answer (score 0):

My question would be, why did someone do this?  It's not a code requirement or a standard practice.

If the grounding electrode system is in order, this wire would be a bonding jumper to a metal pipe and that does not create a hazard.  However, there is usually a jumper between the cold water in and hot water out at the water heater.  If the pipes are all metallic, that would make this bonding jumper unnecessary.  If there is a patchwork of metal and plastic pipe, it's possible this part of the hot water pipework was left floating, and needed to be bonded.

But again, my concern - Was this done just because someone was very on top of bonding a floating portion of the pipes?   Or was there a touch potential on this pipe that made it an issue, people were getting a tingle or a zap when they touched something in the sink area, and this is a band aid fix?

The bonding jumper may eliminate the tingle, but it doesn't fix the fault that was causing the problem - could be dishwasher or garbage disposal or who knows what.

I might have someone look at it, carefully - see what current if any is on that bonding jumper, what potential is on it without the jumper, and see if I can identify the ground fault.  But this is potentially dangerous so I'd recommend calling in reinforcements - call an electrician for this one.